Ways of selecting a subset of a set of integer, given there is wrap around in the integers.
Let there be a set of integers $Z=[1, K]$. There are two parameters, $a$ and $p$, which take integer values. How many ways can we select a subset $T$ of cardinality $(1+a+p)$ from $Z$, such that there is only one subset of $T$ of cardinality $a$ whose elements are consecutive integers? There is wrap around in the integers. For example, for $K=6$, $T=\{1,3,4,6\}$ is not valid as $\{3,4\}$ and $\{6,1\}$ are two sets which have consecutive integers. Another example, for $K=7$, $T=\{1,3,5,7\}$ is valid as $\{7,1\}$ has consecutive integers due to the wrap around.

What have you tried? How much do you know? EG If you ignore the issue of wraparound, would you be able to solve the problem?

So far, for $p< a-1$, I know that I only need to fix a subset of cardinality $a$ and then do $\binom{K-1-a}{p}$. However, for larger $p$, I am running into problems.
If I ignore the wraparound, I will be able to solve. But the wraparound condition can not be ignored.

To deal with the wraparound, 1/ First assume that the subset T is ${1, 2, \ldots a }$, and we need to pick the other $p$ numbers from $ \geq a+2$ without another continuous subset of $a$ numbers. 2/ Given any solution to the problem, show that there is a $a : 1$ map to a solution to the first part. Hence, the number of solutions is $ a \times (1)$.

I took a slightly different approach. I fixed a subset of $T$ as ${1,2,3,\cdots,a}$. Then from the set ${a+2,a+3,\cdots, K-1}$, I selected all those subsets of cardinality $p+1$, say S, such that there is no subset of $S$ of cardinality $a$, having consecutive integers. Do you think this is the correct approach?

Yup. That's essentially what I'm saying with "1/". It can be a tricky calculation, but you indicated that you are able to do it, though it seems like you're having trouble with $ p \geq a$, which is indeed the troublesome case.  $\quad$ Without too much further thought, the way that I would approach it is to set up a recurrence relation for $ R(p, a, n)$ and solve for it. You know the initial values for $ p \leq a-1$.

I think I am doing what you said without calling it a recurrence. Thank you so much :). I will work on it and give an update as soon as I can.
